# How does Photoshop scale images while maintaining the image quality?

Tags: image, image-processing, photoshop

I'm a beginner at Image Processing. I would like to know how Photoshop employs scaling algorithms. For example how an image with a resolution of a few inches is scaled up to a few feet while maintaining the best image quality.

Comment: inches and feet are no measure for resolution. maintaining image quality while upscaling is not possible.

Comment: Fine even if you consider pixels, image quality is somewhat maintained while upscaling in PS @Piglet

Comment: upscaling always comes with a loss of quality. that's just how it is. there are better and worse scaling algorithms but none will "maintain best image quality"

Comment: in case you don't know realize why: an image contains information. upscaling the image means that you increase the number of pixels. but you don't have real new information for those pixels. you can't get information out of nowhere. hence you have to estimate those values from existing pixels by some sort of interpolation. the resulting image has less quality.

Comment: Actually, it's perfectly possible for an upscaled image to not have lost any quality at all. I've been able to 100% reconstruct original images by downscaling stretched images (screenshot of a sprite-based 90s game; _any_ deterioration would've been _really_ noticeable). You just need to use the exact same scaling method that was used for the upscaling. The upscaled image will never be _better_ than the original, of course. But it will not have _less_ quality, either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Photoshop uses [bilinear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_interpolation) and [bicubic interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicubic_interpolation) when resizing. These are essentially weighed averages of nearby pixels.

Look for articles about [image resampling](http://entropymine.com/imageworsener/resample/) to learn more about such techniques.